# Need to hide the variable values in the url

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, url

We had build a website using angular js, html and php. When passing the values between the two pages using state params in angular js. The values are visible in url like below.

## /app/create_addpos/update/9486904359/1820

We don't need to show the real values in url while passing to different page. I don't how to get this. Please help me to acheive.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to "hide" the values on the url, what you can do is once the page "mounted", replace the url by a fake "display url".

by doing this (so the page doesn't get refreshed/redirect):

so if you redirect to:
`/app/create_addpos/update/9486904359/1820`

you can change this to:

```
window.history.pushState("", "", '/app/create_addpos/update/'); // or some other url
```

Do this on the `/app/create_addpos/update/9486904359/1820` page.